# Why does @fontface work sometimes and not other times in Firefox? Fixes?

Tags: firefox, font-face

Does anybody know why @fontface will work sometimes in Firefox but not others?

On this page... http://www.independentink.ca/gameday/indexb.htm you can see 'Design Packages' written in an embedded font. Then, I try to implement some League Gothic on the same page, as seen here... http://ggszabo.com/new/indexb.html and it won't work.

I'm viewing both in FF and one works while the other doesn't. My code is exactly the same on both.

I've searched for answers but none address this problem specifically.

My css is as follows.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'League Gothic';
  src: url('../fonts/League_Gothic.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
    url("../fonts/League_Gothic.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/League_Gothic.svg") format("svg");
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried specifying `!important` ?

Comment: Yeah, i have.

And it works in Chrome and ie just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for local development at least...

"Firefox comes with a very strict "file uri origin" (file:///) policy by default: to have it to behave just as other browsers, go to about:config, filter by fileuri and toggle the following preference:

security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy

Set it to false and you should be able to load local font resources across different path levels."

I have yet to see if it works when published. I have reason to believe that it will.